# Is there some way to integrate different forums?

Tags: linux, open-source, cross-platform, optimization

I am normally reading quora, stack exchange, subreddits, and  discourse forums.

Is there a way to integrate all these feeds?

Comment: This is very broad.  Intergrate into what?  On what OS?

Comment: Into a single feed . Linux

Comment: So you are looking for a [foss feed reader for linux](https://itsfoss.com/feed-reader-apps-linux/)?

Comment: You want a single feed where each item matches certain keywords or conditions such as date for instance?

Comment: Do all of these forums implement RSS or equivalent? Do you want to see the main post only, or also the comments if any?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those specific sites you mentioned, but [Tapatalk](https://www.tapatalk.com/) is a service that is supposed to integrate with forums. I've never actually used it, but I've been to a number of forums that prompt me about Tapatalk.

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381152/1319284), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/rss/) and [discourse](https://meta.discourse.org/t/enabling-rss-feed-on-discourse-setup/55647/8) have RSS feeds. Quora does not since 2017 from what I can tell, but there seem to be [workarounds](https://qr.ae/prwC0d).

So any kind of RSS feed reader will work. Quora will take a little extra work to integrate, but the other three seem straight-forward.